# Team members are unable to see TFS repo

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am unable to configure TFS so that the developers on my team can access and clone a repo onto their local machines.

They all receive the following message:

> You don't have the authority to view the permissions for this object

I have added them as members of the project.
I have even reluctantly made them admins.
However, all attempts to resolve this issue have failed.

Comment: try tracing the effective permissions. there has to be denied somewhere.

Comment: Is there some documentation that you recommend me reading to learn how to do that?

Comment: Not sure about a document but i can pass my own knowledge see if it helps. answer to follow

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions You are probably better off at deleting the permissions you set (minus your admin rights!) and slowly add them back. Typically I use the `Project Contributors` and try to not customize the groups for reasons like this.

Comment: Hi scco, any updates on this question, did your issue been fixed?

Comment: @ScottNimrod I was having this exact same issue with Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS), where a user couldn't see any repos. I tried fiddling with all sorts of permissions and nothing worked. In my case, the problem was the access level for the user. They were added as Stakeholder. Changing it to Basic did the trick.

Answer (score 50):

I followed what [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1602584/ash) suggested above and was able dig around and eventually resolve it for my case. Adding some steps here hopefully to help more people find the right page.

To change access from "Stakeholder" to "Basic":

1. Go to your project page > under "Project Settings", under "General" > "Overview" which is the default, you should see "Process" = "Basic". Click on the word "Basic", that should lead you to your Organization Settings.
2. Under "General" > "Users", you can see that yourself or some users have the access level of "Stakeholder" rather than "Basic". Next step is just to get someone who can, to change that.

Comment: Your answer solved issue in just a minute, and very well explained. I was trying it for hours but no luck.Thanks.!!!

Comment: How do you change Stakeholder to Basic? I'm not following you. I can see I'm a Stakeholder at the Organization Settings, but it cannot be changed there. It's not clickable. And when I go to Project Settings, General, Overview, there is nothing on that page that says "Process=Basic". Under Process it only says Scrum.

Comment: It solved my problem also, thanks! :) Strange behavior of azure devops...

Answer (score 13):

In my case, team members role was stakeholder. It should be **BASIC** to see all repos.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open admin for the team project.
2. navigate to security tab.
3. in the box to add users account you should be able to see the
   effective permissions on the right side.
4. User should have Allowed in the "View project level information"
5. Mouse hover should display "Why" if you click that you should be
   able to see the source of denied permission.

This is relevant to visual studio 2012 i am using btw.

Comment: "View project-level information
Allow" was already set. Not sure what else is required. I have a feeling that they may be using the wrong account credentials.

Comment: You should follow that list to the end and set it to allow. unset permissions implicitly denies permission. [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/change-permission-levels) might help

Answer (score 3):

If you are a "StakeHolder" in azure then, you have No access to Repos in Private Projects.

For my project, We had to purchase a Visual Studio Subscription before the repo setting became available.

[Microsoft Devops - About access levels - Stakeholder access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fget-started%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fget-started%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#stakeholder-access)

> Public versus private feature access:  Stakeholder access grants
>   access to features differently depending on whether you're working
>   from a private or a public project. To learn more about public
>   projects, see What is a public project.
>
> Visual Studio subscription access:  Visual Studio subscribers are
>   entitled to Visual Studio subscription features as a subscriber
>   benefit. When you add those users, be sure to assign them the Visual
>   Studio subscription access level.
>
> The system automatically recognizes their subscription and enables any
>   other features that are included, based on their subscription level.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your team members permission of the corresponding repo. *Web Portal-Settings-Version Control*

[image]

Make sure the Contribute permission is allow.

Also check the permission of groups they are in, cause in TFS **deny trumps allow**.

> If a user belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific
>   permission set to **deny**, that user will not be able to perform
>   tasks that require that permission even if they belong to a group that
>   has that permission set to **allow**.

Answer (score 1):

if you use azure devops server, you can change access from "Stakeholder" to "Basic",

[image]